# How to convert CXF wsdl2java generated client request body from xml to json?

Tags: json, xml, client, cxf, wsdl2java

I use CXF wsdl2java to generate the webservice client code.
It works well.

There is another requirment is that I want to send the webservice request body in JSON format, the default is xml.

So, is there any way to add an intercepter to wsdl2java client that I can custom convert the request body from xml to JSON?

Comment: As an alternative - a this is a long shot - instantiate a JAX-RS client from the generated JAX-WS classes?